# What is the best practices or pattern for creating sync (real time and offline) using Django?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I guess it's better to use WebSockets (channels). But the question is how can I guarantee that every device will have the latest set of data. For example when one device goes offline, then back online is Django channels gonna send messages again to him? Any suggestions for articles or examples? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets  will not do that as after each connection there is a no way for the backend/erver to detect if this connection is same as the user's connection which got disconnected earlier and resend events which failed earlier. Actually, there is no way in general for the websocket connection to detect if frontend received the sent event or the event failed.

What you have to do is write a sync logic in frontend, such that when it reconnects back to server update things that needs to be updated either through API or websockets (whatever you prefer). But the point is that one has to write sync logic at their end. In general, what we do is we store the last sync time and update data in frontend based on supplying that last sync time in multiple APIs, like `fetchNewMessages` and `fetchNewRooms`, if you building a chat application